# Where to place business logic is Symfony 2 model layer?

Tags: symfony, model, symfony-2.2

I'm moving my old codebase to the Symfony 2.2 framework.

In my old code, my Article entity has had a method **getUrl()**, which was returning a URL for current article.

In Symfony i have to use **Router** service to generate such an URLs.

I can't access Router from inside the Entity, cause it's a bad practice and not really supported by the framework.

I can call the router from the Twig template itself using Twig helper **path()** and provide all the arguments (from the Article instance) needed to construct the URL. But this approach is not very good, cause if i'll decide to change URL formatting rules - i will have to find all this calls and rewrite them (not very **DRY**).

I really want to save the business-logic encapsulation here and not to pull all the guts to the view layer.

How should i proceed in this situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an `ArticleManager` class in your service layer, and handle any business logic there. You can pass the router to it through dependency injection.

For your example, `ArticleManager` would have a `getUrl(Article $article)` method which would use the router instance (that you either injected through `__construct` or a separate setter method) to generate the Url based on properties of `$article`, and return it.

This method will ensure that your business logic doesn't pollute the view or controller layers.

Be sure to read up on the [Service Container docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

Comment: Thanks Arms! I was thinking about this approach, just needed a confirmation from someone more experienced )

I'm not sure that i really comfortable with managing model entities from some other class, but looks like this is only viable option.

Comment: If you're coming from an Active Record ORM, this definitely feels like a foreign approach. But over time you'll appreciate the separation of concerns and wonder how you ever managed before ;-)

Comment: @SlavaFominII This is a good solution but, if you have same "model" object, pool them into the same Manger or you'll have a manager (so, a service) for every entity of your application and this, sometimes, isn't desiderable

Comment: @DonCallisto That's the beauty of these manager objects - while typically used for managing one entity, there's nothing stopping you from using as many entities as needed to perform business tasks.

Comment: @Arms: No one told that he hasn't to do for particular reason, I only told that if you have a model object that is equiparable with another, is better to create a unique manager. Of course, this is my point of view